# Trouble with C else, if and scanf

Tags: c

I am new to C and I'm making my first "decent" program. I am facing trouble with my code.

```
char username[] = "root";
char usernametry[10];

scanf("%s",usernametry);

if (usernametry == username)
{
    printf("Welcome ROOT user\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Try again\n");
}
```

Whenever I execute my program, everything works; however, when I try to log in and type `root` as the username, it returns `Try again`. Can someone suggest why this is happening? I am very new to C so I apologize for my lack of C knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) The code has been fixed

Comment: you should accept the answer that helped you by clicking the green 'check' next to it.

Answer (score 3):

`usernametry` and `username` are arrays of type `char`. When you do `usernametry == username`, you are not comparing if two strings are equal, you are comparing the memory address of the first `char` in `usernametry` with the memory address of the first `char` in `username`. In order to compare if two strings are equal, you should use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Also, consider replacing `%s` in your `scanf` with `%9s` so that `usernametry` will never exceed 9 `char`s (which would have been a buffer overflow, as the 10th `char` needs to be `'\0'`, the null character, which is used to terminate C-style strings).

Comment: Better use `9` in the scanf to account for the terminator: `scanf("%9s", usernametry);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare strings using ==, this is not a that-high-level-language. See strcmp() for comparing strings.

Incidentally, what if someone enters a name longer than 10 characters? You're drifting towards a buffer overflow bug in your code ;-)

Comment: Minor:  if someone enters a name longer than 9 characters leads to problems too.

Answer (score 1):

use `strcmp()` functions to compare 2 strings instead of `==`

use of `==` is wrong because in this case you compare address of `usernametry` and `username` and of course they are always differents.

```
if(strcmp(usernametry, username) == 0) // return 0 if equal !=0 if not equal
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **strcmp** to compare two strings:

`if(!strcmp(usernametry,username))`

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are not the same pointer.

Replace by:

```
if (!strcmp(usernametry, username))
```